# Error in panel regression in case of different independent variable r

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to run Fama Macbeth regression by the following code:

```
require(foreign)
require(plm)
require(lmtest)
fpmg <- pmg(return~max_1,df_all_11, index=c("yearmonth","firms" )) 
Fama<-fpmg
coeftest(Fama)
```

It is working when I regress the data using the independent variable named 'max_1'. However when I change it and use another independent variable named 'ivol_1' the result is showing an error. The code is

```
require(foreign)
require(plm)
require(lmtest)
fpmg <- pmg(return~ivol_1,df_all_11, index=c("yearmonth","firms" )) 
Fama<-fpmg
coeftest(Fama)
```

the error message is like this:

```
Error in pmg(return ~ ivol_1, df_all_11, index = c("yearmonth", "firms")) : 
  Insufficient number of time periods
```

or sometimes the error is like this

```
Error in model.frame.default(terms(formula, lhs = lhs, rhs = rhs, data = data,  : 
  object is not a matrix
```

For your convenience, I am sharing my data with you. The data link is

[data frame](https://drive.google.com/open?id=16gX8XxQTWMM8GDO95VGKk8rtVU1MZvhf)

I am wondering why this is happening in case of the different variable in the same data frame. I would be grateful if you can solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem because the variable ivol_1 have a lots of NA so you should impute the NA first then run the pmg function.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved by mice function

```
library(mice)
library(dplyr)
require(foreign)
require(plm)
require(lmtest)
df_all_11<-read.csv("df_all_11.csv.part",sep = ",",header = TRUE,stringsAsFactor = F)

x<-data.frame(ivol_1=df_all_11$ivol_1,month=df_all_11$Month)
imputed_Data <- mice(x, m=3, maxit =5, method = 'pmm', seed = 500)
completeData <- complete(imputed_Data, 3)
df_all_11<-mutate(df_all_11,ivol_1=completeData$ivol_1)
fpmg2 <- pmg(return~ivol_1,df_all_11, index=c("yearmonth","firms"))
coeftest(fpmg2)
```